# ApiGateway: Only one base path mapping is allowed if the base path is empty

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Creating an API Gateway I get this error:

> api-mapping (apimappingXXXXXXX) Only one base path mapping is allowed
>   if the base path is empty. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code:
>   409; Error Code: ConflictException;

where my code is:

```
 // External API Gateway
 const externalApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'external-api-gw',
 {
   apiKeySourceType: apigateway.ApiKeySourceType.AUTHORIZER,
   restApiName: 'external-api',
   deploy: false,
   endpointConfiguration: {
     ...
   },
   policy: new iam.PolicyDocument({
     statements: [
      ..
         ],
       }),
     ]
   })
 }
);

const domainName = externalApi.addDomainName('domain-name', {
 domainName: props.apigatewayRecordName + '.' + props.hostedZone,
 certificate: existingCertificate,
 endpointType: apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
});

const myApiGateway = new route53targets.ApiGateway(externalApi);

// deployment
const apiDeployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, 'deployment', {
  api: externalApi
});

// stage
const apiStage = new apigateway.Stage(this, 'stage', {
  stageName: 'api',
  accessLogDestination: new apigateway.LogGroupLogDestination(logGroup),
  accessLogFormat: apigateway.AccessLogFormat.jsonWithStandardFields(),
  loggingLevel: apigateway.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
  dataTraceEnabled: true,
  deployment: apiDeployment
});
externalApi.deploymentStage = apiStage;
domainName.addBasePathMapping(externalApi, { basePath: 'api', stage: apiStage} );
```

It seems that an empty base path mapping is created automatically and the second one cannot be added.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you share the full code ? `externalApi` & `domainName`

Comment: I updated the code in my question.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the issue is.. but I can share my code whos working if that helps

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, Below you can find the working code snippet:

**Create CfnDomainName:**

```js
// import relevant data from ssm
const certificateArn = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, 'CertificateArn');
const domainNameURL = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, 'ApiCustomDomainUrl');
const certificate = cert.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'Certificate', certificateArn);

// create DomainName
const domainName  = new apigateway.DomainName(this, 'DomainName', {
    domainName: domainNameURL,
    certificate: certificate ,
    endpointType: apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL, 
});
```

**Add base path mapping:**

```js
// create the api
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, id, {
    restApiName: 'API GW ' + id,
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'dev',
    },
    endpointTypes: [apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL]
});

// add new base path to domain name
new apigateway.BasePathMapping(this, 'my-mapping', {
    domainName: domainName,
    restApi: api,
    basePath: 'my-mapping'
});

// add new base path to domain name
new apigateway.BasePathMapping(this, 'my-mapping-two', {
    domainName: domainName,
    restApi: api,
    basePath: 'my-mapping-two'
});
```

More about [BasePathMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.DomainName.html) , [DomainName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.BasePathMapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something changed over the versions, but this does not work with 1.57 of the CDK.

Will generate: "Error: API does not define a default name"